# How to get nextcursorvalue from solr query

Tags: solr

```
solr_url = 'https://exampleurl.com/solr/clst1/select?'
solr_tuples=[
    ('q', '*:*'),
    ('fl', 'id'),
    ('sort', 'id asc'),
    ('rows', '10000000'),
    ('cursorMark', '*')

]
encoded_solr_tuples = urllib.parse.urlencode(solr_tuples)
complete_url = solr_url + encoded_solr_tuples
connection = urlopen(complete_url)
raw_response = simplejson.load(connection)
print(raw_response)
```

raw_response doesnot have nextcursormark. How to get nextcursormark?

Comment: Why do you have `&` before the cursorMark argument and not in front of the others? That would make `&` be encoded as part of the key, wouldn't it?

Comment: I have tried without the & still I don't see nextcursormark unfortunately

Comment: What's the resulting URL? Have you tried opening it manually? Which version of Solr are you using? And since you're using `rows=10000000` - do you have more than `10000000` rows? It'd already return every document available if there's less documents than the `rows` parameter. (however, cursorMark should be returned in any case iirc).

Comment: The number of rows are quite more than that. I have tried with `rows=1` too the result was as expected except for the missing nextcursormark

Comment: What's the resulting URL? Have you tried opening it manually? Which version of Solr are you using?